# 502 Bad Gateway NodeJS/MongoDB AWS Elastic Beantstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am running into a 502 Bad Gateway issue trying to run my NodeJS app on Elastic Beanstalk. I tried to follow a stackoverflow answer that told me to change my starting script from `server.js` to `main.js`, but that didn't work. I'm using env variables that are set up in a `.env` file that is not a part of my git repository, could this cause this error or is it more because of the starting script?

Should this section in my configuration dashboard be changed to my start file?

[image]

Here is my app setup:

Framework: Expressjs

Database: MongoDB

Elastic Beanstalk Server: 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.2.0 running Node.js

I checked my logs and found nothing in my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and the only error section I could find only contained information as to what could cause an error.

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","truncated":"false","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"No start scripts located in package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Add start scripts or place code in a file named server.js or app.js.","severity":"ERROR","timestamp":1425234947517}]}]}
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "expressjs-blog",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.6.5",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.6.1",
    "express-paginate": "0.0.2",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.15",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^3.1.0",
    "serve-favicon": "*",
    "passport" : "~0.1.17",         
    "passport-local" : "~0.1.6",
    "connect-flash" : "~0.1.1",     
    "bcrypt-nodejs" : "latest",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "method-override": "~1.0.0",
    "express-session": "~1.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "*" 
  }
}
```

Here is my `main.js` file:

```
//Load express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the router
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // configure app to use bodyParser()
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true})); // get data from a POST method
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set the port

var DB_CONFIG = process.env.DB_CONFIGURATION;
var AWS_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
var AWS_SECRET_KEY = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY;
var S3_BUCKET = process.env.S3_BUCKET;

var blogDB = require('./config/blogDB.js');
mongoose.connect(blogDB.url);




require('./config/passport.js')(passport);


app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set ejs as the view engine

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the public directory

app.use(session({ secret: 'thisisatest' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());


var routes = require('./app/routes');

app.use(routes); // use routes.js


app.listen(port);
console.log('magic is happening on port' + port);
```

-----------**UPDATE**------------

I added env variables to the Amazon configuration dashboard that will allow it to see where to connect to the database and other variables. I now receive an error log:

`/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2015/03/04 17:12:03 [error] 15978#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "xxxxx-d-xxxxxx-env-xxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/03/04 17:12:03 [error] 15978#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xx, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "xxxxx-d-xxxxx-env-xxxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/03/04 17:16:27 [error] 15978#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xx, server: , request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/translators.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/phpMyAdmin/translators.html", host: "xx.xxx.xx.xx"
2015/03/04 17:20:02 [error] 15978#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "xxx-d-philxxxxlips-env-rqsrxxe92stf.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/03/04 17:20:03 [error] 15978#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xx, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "xxxx-d-xxx-env-rqsre92xxxstf.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! All I had to do was go into Configuration > Container Options and set node command to `node main.js`

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you run `npm start` locally? The error messages says that you have not specified a start script. It's likely that AWS uses `npm start` to spin up your server, and that command seems to be failing.

Try adding this to your package.json:

```
"scripts" : {
     "start" : "node main.js"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try to run `npm start` locally, I am just sent to a blank line in the terminal. Essentially nothing happens. I'm assuming this would seem to be the same as if the command is failing. I added that script to my package.json, but nothing has changed. Any other tips? Maybe something related to the fact `npm start` does nothing?

Comment: Could this be because the server can't get access to my env variables? When I run `node main.js`, it comes up with an error related to no access to mongoDB. This sounds correct, because the access is connected to an env variable. I added my env variables to the Elastic Beanstalk configuration file, but I'm getting the same 502 response

Comment: Actually, now that I set the env variables in the configuration dashboard, I am finally receiving an error log. See edited question for the error log. Not sure how to comprehend the information though.